# new install 15.04 now lost wifi, connects but no ping. also gobi not enabled

Tags: networking, wireless, xubuntu, 15.04

toughbook cf19 mk3 xubuntu 1504 64bit

worked on wifi for a week then lost it. gets IP etc. but no ping not even to local address except local-host. also since upgrading from 1404lts Gobi has never worked. its seen in lsusb and i installed firmware driver but shows not enabled. this is wife's pc so you see the urgency. my life it is worthless until its fixed!
heres paste of the output.

```
lspci -knn  | grep Net -A2
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10f5] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Matsushita Electric Industrial Co., Ltd. Device [10f7:8338]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1201]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

HERES OUTPUT OF WIRELESS-INFO:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/11303209
hope this makes things work!

well wifi has just randomly started working again! no reboot or nufin! still cant use the gobi but i suppose i should post another question about that. 
now the laptop wifi is working again, is there a way to compare its current state to find out why it wasnt working in case it happens again?

Comment: Please specify what wifi adapter you are asking about. Is it usb or internal, etc? And what is Gobi, that never worked?

Comment: the gobi is panasonic wwan modem internal and shows in lsusb. the wifi is intel wifilink 5100 internal pci

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add there output of "lspci -knn | grep Net -A2" terminal command.

Comment: i put a pastie link, not sure if thats polite to post output here

Comment: Why don't you just paste text right to your question? And please also add "rfkill list"

Comment: am i getting close yet? the laptop is dual boot win7 so i have the driver files and firmware. think win7 32 bit, so maybe not work?

Comment: Please [run the WiFi diagnostics](/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. This will gather a bit more info on IP and routing setup, signal strengths, and kernel log message.

Comment: ok will do later. now bluetooth gone down as well so laptop getting ready for bin. have pulled battery and wait half hour

Comment: its started working... can i quickly find out how or why while its still up and good?